# mvn tomcat:run resolving jstl taglibs dependencies

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I have a simple `maven-webapp` project. After executing `mvn tomcat:run`, when I brows the project I get below exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:148)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:449)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1396)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

But It works fine If I manually copy `.war` file to tomcat `webapps` directory.

This is what I have in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
       <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
       <version>6.0.26</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
       <version>6.0.26</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved, `<scope>provided</scope>` should be removed from `jstl`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>          
    </dependency>
```